# setWindowLong, cannot remove WS_POPUP with different users

Tags: python, security, winapi

I want to pull a Window into another one. Therfore I use python with pywin32.

I want to remove with setWindowLong the WS_POPUP style.

This works fine, when the loggedin user and the processes involved are the same.

But when the processes are running under an diffrent user, I get an Access Denied Error.

Thanks for your Post.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [SetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) contains the following section on the *hWnd* argument:

> The SetWindowLongPtr function fails if the process that owns the window specified by the hWnd parameter is at a higher process privilege in the UIPI hierarchy than the process the calling thread resides in.

If the call fails with an *Access Denied Error*, then you are calling from a process with a lower integrity level than the target process.

There is no suggested solution to circumvent that security firewall, although requesting *UIAccess* through an application manifest may work (see [Security Considerations for Assistive Technologies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671610.aspx)). This is meant for assistive technology applications, and should not be abused by software that isn't.

---

*Bonus reading: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)*

Comment: Thanks IInspectable,

Comment: But that is not the problem the two processes have the integrity level High, that means both are running as admin. I also gave the logged in user administrative rights (but only for testing).

Comment: @held_a: Giving the logged in user administrative privileges doesn't automatically transfer those to processes launched under that account. By default, processes are still launched using the minimum required (use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to see the actual integrity level). If you need your application to run with administrative privileges, you need to request them (e.g. through [UAC information in the manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx)).

Comment: The processes are running under an Admin account, they have both the integrity Level High (in my knowledge means this they have admin rights) and they are at the same level, that means setWindowLongPtr should work. I gave the logged in user admin right, because i thought this has an effect on my behaviour, but it hasn't. When my processes have the integrity level high i don't have to change the manifest file?

Comment: @held_a: Have you verified that both processes run at high integrity level (using a tool like Process Explorer)?

Comment: Yes, I have verified it with Process Explorer.

Comment: @held_a: If I understand, you are trying to call `SetWindowLongPtr` from a process running under the user account A, to change the window styles of a window owned by a process running under another user account B. This is not allowed. In case you missed it: If you are trying to establish cross-thread window hierarchies, and the participating windows aren't in on the joke, this is going to break, sooner or later, 100% guaranteed. A deadlock is the most common outcome.

Comment: No, both process the calling process and the reciving process are running under the same account only the user which is logged in is another. Little background, We have an application which has sevral processes, some processes integrate devices into the system. Those devices have sometimes external Application to change Settings which are not integrated, Therefor we have another process(WindowManager) who creates a window pulls the external Application in the window and brings the window on top. Both, the WindowManager and the external Application runs with the same Account.

Comment: If this is a good idea i don't know especially to pull the window into another, but to change this it is not the case at the moment. But in my opinion it should work, perhabs there are some problems, that the windowhandle is owned by the Desktop of the other user???

Comment: @held_a: The *Access Denied* error is the least of your worries. If I understand this, you are trying to re-parent a window, whose source code you cannot change, across thread boundaries. This is dangerous territory, and will more than likely break. See [I warned you: The dangers of attaching input queues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080801-00/?p=21393) and [AttachThreadInput is like taking two threads and pooling their money into a joint bank account, where both parties need to be present ...](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043) for details.

Comment: I see your warning, and I have to think about it, because we made this for several years without problems, but perhaps there is something different. But to open my mind, i don't understand what is going wrong.